# How to send array to other function.(Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to send array to other function

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<input type="button" value="chk" id="go" />
<script>
    $(function() 
    {
        var c = 1;
        var i = 5;
        var data = [[]];

        for ( c = 1 ; c <= i ; c++ )
        {
            data[c] = [];
            data[c]['proDetails'] = 'asdf'+c;
            data[c]['proDeCount'] = 'qwer'+c;
        }

        c=1;
        for ( c = 1 ; c <= i ; c++ )
        {
                $('#test').text($('#test').text() + " " + data[c]['proDetails'] + " " + data[c]['proDeCount']);
        }

        $('#go').click(function()
        {
            test(data);
        });
    })

    function test()
    {
        var c = 1;
        var i = 5;
        for ( c = 1 ; c <= i ; c++ )
        {
                $('#test2').text($('#test2').text() + " " + data[c]['proDetails'] + " " + data[c]['proDeCount']);
        }
    }
</script>
```

From this code `<div id="test"></div>` it can show data form array.
But `<div id="test2"></div>` it can't show data from array.
It has some error "ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declaire it in function

```
function test(data)
    {
        if(typeof data != 'undefined')
        {
            var c = 1;
            var i = 5;
            for ( c = 1 ; c <= i ; c++ )
            {
                $('#test2').text($('#test2').text() + " " + data[c]['proDetails'] + " " + data[c]['proDeCount']);
            }
        }
    }
```

other thing you can do is global the var like:

```
<script>
var data = [[]]; // <---- here
    $(function() 
    {
        var c = 1;
        var i = 5;


        for ( c = 1 ; c <= i ; c++ )
        {
            data[c] = [];
            data[c]['proDetails'] = 'asdf'+c;
            data[c]['proDeCount'] = 'qwer'+c;
        }

        c=1;
        for ( c = 1 ; c <= i ; c++ )
        {
                $('#test').text($('#test').text() + " " + data[c]['proDetails'] + " " + data[c]['proDeCount']);
        }

        $('#go').click(function()
        {
            test(data);
        });
    })

    function test()
    {
        var c = 1;
        var i = 5;
        for ( c = 1 ; c <= i ; c++ )
        {
                $('#test2').text($('#test2').text() + " " + data[c]['proDetails'] + " " + data[c]['proDeCount']);
        }
    }
</script>
```